# effective labelling in multilabel classification

Tags: categorical-encoding, keras, multilabel

I am working on a multilabel classification problem with 44 features and 2 labels. Label2 is a binary (0,1) and Label1 had label encoding done on it up to ten (1,2...10).

I did one-hot encoding on Label1 so that I ended up with a vector of 11 components, 10 indicating Label1 classes and the last component indicating Label2 classes. So a possible output is like [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]. However, I feel that part of the lack of performance of the model is because the model deems a zero output vector more correct than a vector of 1s since a possible output contains significantly more zeros than 1s. So I think that it is leaning towards a zero output vector and having trouble producing higher than 0.5 on components that should be 1.

Is there a way to address this? Here is my DNN, but I think the change probably needs to be made in the data preproccessing. Thanks!

P.S. Sorry for my weird ML vocab, it's underdevelopment.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2024, input_dim=42, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
 
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
 
model.add(Dense(11, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['binary_accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train,Y_train_Labels, epochs =9, validation_split = 0.2, batch_size =32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it correct that you have one label that can be one of 10 categories (mutually exclusive) and (at least theoretically) the second label can be either 0 or 1 no matter which categories the first one takes (of course there might be strong correlations)?

If so, using a binary crossentropy does not seem right - it assumes that multiple ones of the 10 categories could apply at the same time, and does not reflect that at least one of the 10 categories must apply and at least one of the two categories for label 2 must apply (if I understood your description correctly). If I described it correctly, you should idally have two separate output heads, one with one-hot-encoded 10 categories and categorical cross-entropy loss and the second one with binary cross entropy.

Comment: yes you're correct. and wow u blew my mind. so i should have 2 neurons in the last dense layer? but then how would i set two different loss functions for the same layer? but thanks, that gives me something to work with!

Comment: also, this means the activation function for the 10 categories output would be softmax right?

Comment: It's 2 output heads, one with 10 neurons (if target is one-hot-encoded) & one with 1 neuron (for binary, or 2 if one-hot-encoded into 2 columns). You can either apply softmax to the 10 & sigmoid to the 1, or you leave them on the unconstrained scale & use a loss function that effectively does this for you (e.g. keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)). To get 2 heads, you probably switch from `Sequential()` to the functional API, but that's not so bad & this example in the docs has a two-outputs: https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/#manipulate-complex-graph-topologies.